# Order and OrderProduct

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-relationship, shopping-cart

I seem to be having a problem when handling an order from my shopping cart. Firstly I will have to create an Instance of a Order(OrderId,CustId,...)....but in OrderProduct how will I assign the OrderId (it is set has identity specification in the sql), because it is required a foreign key in OrderProduct in my database.

```
    public class Order
    {
        String CustomerId;
        String shipping_firstname;
        String shipping_lastname;
        String shipping_address;
        String shipping_city;
        String payment_firstname;
        String payment_lastname;
        String payment_address;
        String payment_city;
}
```

OrderProduct Class,

```
    public class OrderProduct
    {
        String OrderId;
        String ProductId;
        String Quanity;
}
```

Comment: I think that you have a bad object model... You should use composition.

Comment: Actually, this is what was suggested to me for my Database. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622652/relationship-between-customer-and-order-in-a-shopping-cart

Comment: The database is correct... I meant the objects. For example, Order have a Costumer (the object Costumer), not a costumer ID. The costumer's ID would be accessible by Order.Costumer.Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make your objects represent things in real life. Now this might sound a little weird but an object named `OrderProduct` doesn't represent anything in real life and also is bad design. What you are after is a relationship between `Product` and `Order`. What about a `List<Product>` in the class `Order`? You can fill this list with products and remove products easily. Then when interacting with your database you make a record in your table `OrderProduct` for each item in the list.

Have a look at this to get an idea:

```
public class Product
{
 int productID;
 string name;
}

public class Order
{
 int orderID;
 Customer customer;
 List<Product> products;
 DateTime orderDate;
}
```

You seem to be mixing paradigms. Be aware that you are doing Object-Oriented Programming with a Relational Database. You shouldn't mix those two up. There is, for example, no object that represents a Table in your database. An object represents an object in the real world, and it's properties may be stored in a combination of tables. An Order is something that was made by a customer, has a list of products on it, quantities, total price, etc. You cannot store this 1 object into 1 record in your database, as you know from applying normalisation in your relational DB. So 1 object results in several records in your DB.

Often OOP programmers make a "Data-Layer" or "Tier" in their programs, that "converts" from OOP to relational before storing to the DB.

Comment: OrderProducts wouldn't be there then, because `Order` has a collection of `Product`. Your `OrderProduct` class doesn't represent an object in the real world, it represents a relation between 2 objects. In OOP you don't make an object that represents a relation, you just make the relation. I've done that by giving `Order` a `List<Product>`. It defines a relation of 1 `Order` having many `Products` (therefore a list of them). also there is a relation between 1 Order and 1 Customer (therefore no list, just 1). Exactly like in your DB.

Comment: DBs that do Object-Oriented do exist, but I assumed (based also on your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622652) that you are using a relational one. Long debates exist about whether OO-databases or relational ones are better for OOP, but this goes beyond the scope of your question here. And if you want the best of both worlds, I would suggest LINQ to SQL. It provides business objects on one end, and saves those in your relational DB on the other end: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx

Comment: @Bazzz `OrderProduct` or `OrderItem` class would be desirable, if not necessary, in my opinion. Every order can have multiple quantities of the same product and storing multiple copies of the same product in a list would make it redundant.